# Couldn’t handle the Kit Seems like your server is missing the PHP zip module

Tags: wordpress, elementor

"Couldn’t handle the Kit Seems like your server is missing the PHP zip module. Install it on your server or contact your site host for further instructions". This pops up while trying to upload a kit file in Elementor plugin.

I have enabled unfiltered file uploads too while in localhost using xampp.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue while working on a local WordPress website and tried to import a template in elementor i fixed it by navigating to \xampp\php\php.ini and searching for the following line
`;extension=zip`
then changing the line to
`extension=zip` which removes it as a code comment, don't for get to restart your xampp server.

https://community.apachefriends.org/viewtopic.php?t=82728&p=278561